# Django: Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

When I am trying to following command django give a following error.

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

and django error is

```
CommandError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
applicant.GalleryImage.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install pillow".
applicant.Speaker.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install pillow".
```

install packages in my virtualenv

```
(Dev-Env)➜  applicantWeb git:(master) ✗ pip freeze
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
Django==1.7.1
django-mongodb-engine==0.5.2
djangotoolbox==1.6.2
ipython==3.1.0
oauthlib==0.7.2
Pillow==2.8.1
PyJWT==1.3.0
pymongo==3.0.2
python-openid==2.2.5
python-social-auth==0.2.10
requests==2.7.0
requests-oauthlib==0.5.0
six==1.9.0
wheel==0.24.0
```

I am tried to install following command still that error come.

```
pip install pillow
```

what should I do?

Comment: First, did `pip install pillow` succeed?

Comment: Second, is it possible that you have two different Python installations, and your `pip` is from one Python, while your Django is using the other? (This is very common for Mac users who install an extra Python 2.7 alongside the one Apple pre-installed.)

Comment: More generally, can you tell us what platform you're on (including version), which Python and Django versions you have, and how you installed them?

Comment: I am using  python2.7 and django1.7.1

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't try to cram information into comments. Also, answering less than half the questions you're asked means it will take more than twice as long to help you, at best.